# Cloud Run Service not picking up client correct IP address

Tags: node.js, socket.io, google-cloud-run

I have a service hosted on Google Cloud Run. The service uses socket io whenever the service is up and running.

When a socket client connects to the service I have the following function that gets the ip address of the connected client from the socket as shown below and then I am hitting this [GeoPlugin Link](http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=$%7Bip%7D) with the retrieved IP

```
    async getSocketIP(socket) {
        let { headers, address } = socket.handshake;
        let { origin } = headers;
        let ip = headers['x-forwarded-for'];
        let userAgent = headers['user-agent'];
        try {
            let locationPointUrl = `http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=${ip}`;
            let { data: location } = await axios.get(locationPointUrl);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Error get client online IP on Socket IO`);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, irrespective of the User's Location the IP always resolves to US.

I have a custom domain mapped to the cloud run service via Domain Mapping.

What could be the reason the IP of the Client is always US IP?

Please note that this same service when hosted on Heroku gets the correct IP address of the connected client.

So, I'm very certain that it has something to do with Cloud Run.

All my services on Cloud Run are on US-CENTRAL1

Comment: Cloud Run provides the correct IP address as per your example. I just used your service for my IP and it thinks I am in Chicago instead of Seattle. Debug and print the IP address to make sure it is correct. If it is, then the issue is with the geoplugin service. Note: address detection via IP address is **NOT** reliable.

Comment: @JohnHanley This is rather weird because the same service above with exactly the same lines of code when deployed on heroku is getting the correct location of the user. The issue only happens when I moved the service to Cloud Run. Extremely weird

Comment: Did you follow my advice or are you debugging this blind?

Comment: I did. The IP address retrieved by heroku is totally different from the one retrieved under cloud run

Comment: The one by cloud run is absolutely wrong

Comment: Cloud Run provides the correct IP address. You are probably reading `x-forwarded-for` incorrectly. Do have a load balancer, proxy, Cloudflare, etc in front of Cloud Run?

Comment: The one by heroku is absolutely correct

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes we have Cloudflare in front of Cloud Run. Could that be the reason? If yes, what can we do?

Comment: Does Cloud Run have DDos Protection? If yes is it safe for us to remove Cloudflare in front of the Cloud Run service?

Comment: Also, we have no custom Load balancer in front of Cloud Run. We assume there is already a Load balancer in front of Cloud Run services. We used the default settings

Comment: Cloudflare is a proxy. As I requested, post the contents of `x-forwarded-for`. Most likely the IP address you are fetching is the Cloudflare entry. `x-forwarded-for` is a list of IP addresses. https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/http-request-headers/#x-forwarded-for

Comment: Cloudflare provides the `CF-Connecting-IP` HTTP header with the real client IP address.

Comment: Post a new question reqarding Cloud Run DDoS protection.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I got it working with `CF-Connecting-IP` header. Thank you very much

Comment: Post an answer with your solution so that your question is answered.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who may experience something like this in the future.

We had Cloudflare sitting in front of Cloud Run.

So, to get the correct Client's IP address all we had to do was retrieve it from `cf-connecting-ip` header instead of `x-forwarded-for`.

So, the modified and working code now becomes:

```
   async getSocketIP(socket) {
        let { headers, address } = socket.handshake;
        let { origin } = headers;
        let ip = headers['cf-connecting-ip'] ?? headers['x-forwarded-for']; //Notice the difference
        let userAgent = headers['user-agent'];
        try {
            let locationPointUrl = `http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=${ip}`;
            let { data: location } = await axios.get(locationPointUrl);
        } catch (e) {
           console.log(`Error get client online IP on Socket IO`);
        }
    }
```